# How can the friction drag be calculated for a moving and spinning disk on a 2D surface?

Tags: simulation, physics

Let's consider a disk with mass m and radius R on a surface where friction u also involved. When we give this disk a starting velocity v in a direction, the disk will go towards that direction and slow down and stop.

In case the disk has a rotation (or spin with the rotational line perpendicular on the surface) w beside the speed then the disk won't move on a line, instead bend. Both the linear and angular velocity would be 0 at the end.

How can this banding/curving/dragging be calculated? Is it possible to give analytical solution for the X(v,w,t) function, where X would give the position of the disk according to it's initial v w at a given t?

Any simulation hint would be also fine. 
I imagine, depending on w and m and u there would be an additional velocity which is perpendicular to the linear velocity and so the disk's path would bend from the linear path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to simulate this, I'd probably recommend something like dividing up the contact surface between the disk and the table into a radial grid. Compute the relative velocity and the force at each point on the grid at each time step, then sum up the forces and torques (r cross F) to get the net force F and the net torque T on the disk as a whole. Then you can apply the equations F=(m)(dv/dt) and T=(I)(dw/dt) to determine the differential changes in v and w for the next time step.

For what it's worth, I don't think a flat disk would curve under the influence of either a frictional force (velocity-independent) or a drag force (linearly proportional to velocity).

Comment: this probably could be simulated but i'll just stick to the idea of velocity independence :)

Answer (score 2):

A ball will move in a large arc with spin, but a [uniform] disk on a 2D surface will not.

For the disk it's center of spin is the same as it's center of gravity, so there is no torque applied.  (As mentioned by duffymo, a nonuniform disk will have a torque applied.)

For a uniform ball, if the axis of the spin is not perpendicular to the table, this causes the ball to experience a rotational torque which causes it to move in a slight arc.  The arc has a large radius, and the torque is slight, so usually friction makes the ball stop quickly.

If there was a sideways velocity, the ball would move along a parabola, like a falling object.  The torque component (and the radius of the arc) can be computed in the same way you do for a precessing top.  It's just that the ball sits at the tip of the top (err....) and the bottom is "imaginary".

Top equation: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/HBASE/top.html

`omega_p = mgr/I/omega`

where

```
omega_p = rotational velocity...dependent on how quickly you want friction to slow the ball
m = ball mass
g = 9.8 m/s^2 (constant)
r = distance from c.g. (center of ball) to center, depends on angle of spin axis (solve for this)
omega = spin rate of ball
I = rotational inertia of a sphere
```

My 2 cents.

Comment: I miss the "good" ol' days when rigid body rotation was just a problem on a test ;-) Good observation though.

Answer (score 1):

Numerical integration of Newton's laws of motion would be what I'd recommend.   Draw the free body diagram of the disk, give the initial conditions for the system, and numerically integrate the equations for acceleration and velocity forward in time.  You have three degrees of freedom: x, y translation in the plane and the rotation perpendicular to the plane.  So you'll have six simultaneous ODEs to solve: rates of change of linear and angular velocities, rates of change for two positions, and the rate of change of angular rotation.

Be warned: friction and contact make that boundary condition between the disk and the table non-linear.  It's not a trivial problem.

There could be some simplifications by treating the disk as a point mass.  I'd recommend looking at Kane's [Dynamics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070378460) for a good understanding of the physics and how to best formulate the problem.

I'm wondering if the bending of the path that you're imagining would occur with a perfectly balanced disk.  I haven't worked it out, so I'm not certain.  But if you took a perfectly balanced disk and spun it about its center there'd be no translation without an imbalance, because there's no net force to cause it to translate.  Adding in an initial velocity in a given direction wouldn't change that.

But it's easy to see a force that would cause the disk to deviate from the straight path if there was an imbalance in the disk.  If I'm correct, you'll have to add an imbalance to your disk to see bending from a straight line.  Perhaps someone who's a better physicist than me could weigh in.

Comment: I think the OP is assuming that frictional force is proportional to relative speed - and since the relative speed of a rotating disk v. the table is greater on one side of the disk than the other, there would be an imbalance in the frictional force. But AFAIK friction is appx. velocity-independent.

Comment: Good point David, you might be right.  I haven't worked it all out, and I'm not a physicist.

Comment: I'm a physics grad student so you'd think I should know these things ;-) I tried to calculate it but Mathematica is having trouble with the integral... I still think it won't curve though. Interestingly, for a drag force proportional to velocity at each point, there's also no curve...

Comment: If drag were proportional to velocity, it would be called viscous, and would be a lot easier to model. Friction is tricky because of the discontinuities. I've seen solvers that stop, back up, and search for the times at which transitions occur.

Comment: Exactly, Michael.  If we coat that table top with a lubricant we've got a different problem.  "Stick/slip" is a very hard problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

When you say friction u, I'm not sure what you mean. Usually there is a coefficient of friction C, such that the friction F of a sliding object = C * contact force.

The disk is modeled as a single object consisting of some number of points arranged in circles about the center.
For simplicity, you might model the disk as a hexagon evenly filled with points, to make sure every point represents equal area.

The weight w of each point is the weight of the portion of the disk that it represents.
It's velocity vector is easily computed from the velocity and rotation rate of the disk.
The drag force at that point is minus its weight times the coefficient of friction, times a unit vector in the direction of its velocity.

If the velocity of a point becomes zero, its drag vector is also zero.
You will probably need to use a tolerance about zero, else it might keep jiggling.

To get the total deceleration force on the disk, sum those drag vectors.

To get the angular deceleration moment, convert each drag vector to an angular moment about the center of the disk, and sum those.

Factor in the mass of the disk and angular inertia, then that should give linear and angular acclerations.

For integrating the equations of motion, make sure your solver can handle abrupt transitions, like when the disk stops.
A simple Euler solver with really fine stepsize might be good enough.

Comment: Euler integration is explicit, which in my experience imposes severe restrictions on time step to maintain stability.  I'd recommend an implicit integration method for better stability.

Comment: @duffymo: You're right if the system is stiff. i.e. if the eigenvalues of the Jacobian differ by orders of magnitude. I'm doubtful of that in this case.

Comment: ... also the discontinuities when velocities cross zero are problematic for any continuous solver. I thought the euler method would get the least confused. It's probably necessary to shrink the time step as the disk slows, until getting below a threshold.

Comment: ... Sorry to keep commenting. The weight distribution of disk matters a lot. A possible simplification might be to model it as a small number of points at its periphery, like 2, 3, or 4, since periphery points will dominate its rotational moment.

Comment: Nice points, Michael.  I've enjoyed the conversation, even if it's what SO is supposed to be.  Personally, I have no feel whatsoever for the eigenvalues of this system, but perhaps you're correct.

Comment: @duffymo: We get stiff systems in the pharma field where (e.g.) equilibration of drug between capillaries and organ tissue, or between different components of blood, may be much faster than between gut and bloodstream.

Comment: Fantastic stuff, Michael.  Sounds like you're doing some great work.  I used to be a mechanical engineer.  I used to simulate non-linear problems in mechanics and heat transfer for a large manufacturer.  It was wonderful work.   So I know a bit about the physics, but I defer to real physicists.

Comment: @duffymo: I was a mechanical engineer too. I think it's a different perspective on engineering than software engineering is. Thanks for your feedback.